# Stream Builder load more data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to load more data once I reach the end of the stream builder, everytime I reach the end, the stream builder reloads and bounces back to the beginning, and it does not allow me to scroll down ( keep reload and bounce back to the top).

What I tried is once I reach the end, increase the limit from the firebase, but I am not sure what the problem is.. anyone can help me with this?

Here is the sample code for what I want to do

```
  _onEndScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    //loadToTrue();
    setState(() {
      documentLimit = documentLimit + 10;
    });
  }



 StreamBuilder(
              initialData: cache,
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("timeline")
                      .doc(widget.currentUser.id)
                      .collection('timelinePosts')
                      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                      .limit(documentLimit)
                      .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                items = streamSnapshot.data != null &&
                        streamSnapshot.data.docs != null
                    ? streamSnapshot.data.docs
                    : [];

                List<Post> posts =
                    items.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();


                cache = streamSnapshot.data;

                return !streamSnapshot.hasData ||
                        streamSnapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting
                    ? Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                    : NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                          if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                            _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                                    parent: ScrollPhysics()),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: items.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, i) =>
                                    timelineDecision == "follow"
                                        ? posts[i]
                                        : postsLocal[i])));
              })
```

and this is code for all

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:fluttershare/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/upload.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/upload_limit.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/post.dart';

import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  final User currentUser;

  Timeline({this.currentUser});
  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  QuerySnapshot cache;
  List<Post> posts;
  List<Post> postsLocal;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> items;
  List<String> followingList = [];
  String timelineDecision = "local";

  String address = "Norman";

  ScrollController listScrollController;
  int documentLimit = 5;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getFollowing();
  }

  getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
        .doc(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .get();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        followingList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
      });
    }
  }

  setTimeline(String timelineDecision) {
    setState(() {
      this.timelineDecision = timelineDecision;
    });
  }

  buildToggleTimeline() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => setTimeline("follow"),
          child: Text('Following',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: timelineDecision == 'follow'
                      ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                      : Colors.grey)),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setTimeline("local"),
            child: Text('Local',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: timelineDecision == 'local'
                        ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                        : Colors.grey)),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }

  _onEndScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    //loadToTrue();
    setState(() {
      documentLimit = documentLimit + 10;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Entango'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              onSelected: choiceAction,
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Timelimit post"),
                      value: 1,
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Normal post"),
                      value: 2,
                    )
                  ]),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search())),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildToggleTimeline(),
          Divider(
            height: 0.0,
          ),
          //buildSlider(),

          StreamBuilder(
              initialData: cache,
              stream: timelineDecision == "follow"
                  ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("timeline")
                      .doc(widget.currentUser.id)
                      .collection('timelinePosts')
                      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                      .limit(documentLimit)
                      .snapshots()
                  : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("postsLocalRef")
                      .doc(address)
                      .collection("userPosts")
                      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                      .limit(documentLimit)
                      .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                items = streamSnapshot.data != null &&
                        streamSnapshot.data.docs != null
                    ? streamSnapshot.data.docs
                    : [];

                List<Post> posts =
                    items.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();

                List<Post> postsLocal =
                    items.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();

                cache = streamSnapshot.data;

                return !streamSnapshot.hasData ||
                        streamSnapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting
                    ? Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                    : NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                          if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                            _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                                    parent: ScrollPhysics()),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: items.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, i) =>
                                    timelineDecision == "follow"
                                        ? posts[i]
                                        : postsLocal[i])));
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void choiceAction(int value) {
    if (value == 1) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Upload_limit(
                    currentUser: currentUser,
                  )));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Upload(
                    currentUser: currentUser,
                  )));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464078/how-to-get-an-infinite-scroll-with-listview-from-firestore-with-flutter). Does it answer your question?

Comment: @FaridShumbar Thank you for your comment, but it does not ... :C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few issues I could find. One of them is using StreamBuilder to fetch paged data. While it might be great in theory but it won't work in case of Firebase as Firebase is providing Stream. So every-time, setState is called, a new steam will be created. I have wrote sample app for fetching data from firestore in paginated way.

```
//main.dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const PAGE_SIZE = 30;

  bool _allFetched = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<ColorDetails> _data = [];
  DocumentSnapshot? _lastDocument;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchFirebaseData();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchFirebaseData() async {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    Query _query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("sample_data")
        .orderBy('color_label');
    if (_lastDocument != null) {
      _query = _query.startAfterDocument(_lastDocument!).limit(PAGE_SIZE);
    } else {
      _query = _query.limit(PAGE_SIZE);
    }

    final List<ColorDetails> pagedData = await _query.get().then((value) {
      if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        _lastDocument = value.docs.last;
      } else {
        _lastDocument = null;
      }
      return value.docs
          .map((e) => ColorDetails.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();
    });

    setState(() {
      _data.addAll(pagedData);
      if (pagedData.length < PAGE_SIZE) {
        _allFetched = true;
      }
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == _data.length) {
              return Container(
                key: ValueKey('Loader'),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }
            final item = _data[index];
            return ListTile(
              key: ValueKey(
                item,
              ),
              tileColor: Color(item.code | 0xFF000000),
              title: Text(
                item.label,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: _data.length + (_allFetched ? 0 : 1),
        ),
        onNotification: (scrollEnd) {
          if (scrollEnd.metrics.atEdge && scrollEnd.metrics.pixels > 0) {
            _fetchFirebaseData();
          }
          return true;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorDetails {
  final String label;
  final int code;
  ColorDetails(this.code, this.label);

  factory ColorDetails.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ColorDetails(json['color_code'], json['color_label']);
  }

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'color_code': code,
      'color_label': label,
    };
  }
}
```

In case you are interested, you can checkout the article I have written as well at https://blog.litedevs.com/infinite-scroll-list-using-flutter-firebase-firestore

Comment: What should we do if we need to listen to the changes? like listen when a doc added/removed/updated?

Comment: In that case you should use StreamSubscription of documents in initState. Once data arrives, set one of the local variables to data and call setState. Use the local variable to display list of data. Don't forget to cancel the subscription in dispose.