# How to OUTPUT randomly generated map key from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, key-value

I have a function called **pushRequest** that sets value in the Firestore.
The data I am trying to push is a **Map<String, Map<String, String>>**, and the **kEY** to the map is randomly generated to i am having trouble Pulling the data from the Firestore using StreamBuilders. Could anyone help me with this issue or is it even possible to Pull data without knowing the **KEY**

[image: Image of the Firestore]

```
String createId() {
    String date = formatDate(DateTime.now(), [yyyy, mm, dd]);
    String string = randomAlphaNumeric(5).toUpperCase();
    String id = '$date-$string';
    return id.toString();
  }

pushRequest({
    @required int categpryId,
    @required String location,
    @required String fullName,
    @required String emailId,
    @required String mobileNumber,
    @required String date,
    @required String comment,
    @required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    String orderId = createId();
    var user = context.read<User>();
    var dataMap = {
      "categoryId": categpryId,
      "location": location,
      "fullname": fullName,
      "emailId": emailId,
      "mobileNumber": mobileNumber,
      "date": date,
      "comment": comment,
    };
    _firebaseFirestore.collection("Active").doc("1").set(
      {
        orderId: dataMap,
      },
    );
    
  }
```

Comment: What is the exact data you want to get?

Comment: The data in the documnet "1" which has the map KEY as 20210220-61KP0

Comment: And this KEY 20210220-61KP0 is randomly generated so idk how to pull its data

Comment: Have you tried to get the document as a Map and iterate through its content?

Comment: No  how do I do that 

Comment: By simply using [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()). Does it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all from a Firestore collection in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611369/get-all-from-a-firestore-collection-in-flutter)