# Flutter & Firestore - error when calling get() on whole collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm using cloud firestore in a Flutter web project. Whenever I call get() on an entire collection (rather than on a single document in the collection), I get the following error:

`Locations: No module for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-firestore.js`

This happens on a collection with about 425 documents - if I limit the results, or call get on a smaller collection it works fine.

This is a valid operation according to the official docs: `https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection` with no indication that it's limited by number of docs, etc. Also this same code was working fine (with the same number of docs) when I was doing the same thing on a Flutter macOS app, until recently I switched it to web.

I'm initializing Firebase in the flutter main() instead of in index.html, as now recommended by the most recent documentation. All firebase-related packages are their latest versions.

If this is indeed an issue related to too many documents then it would at least be nice if the documentation mentioned this limitation or the error message mentioned that, but that is not the case, and really it's not THAT much data, which leads me to believe there is some sort of bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: is this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65589664/15774176) helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav No unfortunately it doesn't - this is already what I'm doing that causes the error. The problem is that everything stops at `await _collectionRef.get();` and it prints out the "no module for..." message over and over again.